# Testing react-hook-form's Controller API using enzyme / Jest

Tags: jestjs, react-hook-form, enzyme-to-snapshot

Is there a way to test a component that uses [react-hook-form's Controller API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) using Jest/enzyme?

Kindly take a look at this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dirac-499io?file=/src/App.tsx) to see what my component looks like

I did try mocking `Controller` using the below for a snapshot test;

```
jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
  Controller: () => (<></>),
  useForm: () => ({
    control: () => ({}),
    handleSubmit: () => jest.fn(),
  }),
}))
```

But then the inputs are not rendered because the mocked Controller would return `null` (because of the `<></>`).

Any idea how to go about this, or must I use `testing library` to have a chance at writing a test for this?

Comment: I have same problem too. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Hey @PrieyudhaAkaditaS... I didn't get how to mock the `Controller` component.

I switched to the hook version - [useController](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller) - and then I was able to mock that similar to how `useForm` is mocked in the question.