# React testing react-hook-form useForm

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, ts-jest

I am wondering how to test component that use react-hook-form. Control object is passed to children component `DimensionInput`

I used suggested in ([How to call or mock useForm on jest react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71761202/how-to-call-or-mock-useform-on-jest-react-native?fbclid=IwAR2O-vjPIfaFbtZfMaw82s3lB0lRbbPZA-puWCkS8zvV7D9yIWFgd_7J4v4)) solution but stil getting error

````
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  it('renders correct text', () => {
    jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-hook-form'),
      Controller: () => <></>,
      useForm: () => ({
        control: () => ({}),
        handleSubmit: () => jest.fn(),
      }),
    }));

    const { control } = useForm({
      mode: 'onChange',
    });
    const { queryByText } = render(
      <DimensionsInput fieldId={'id'} buttonAction={null} control={control} />,
    );

    expect(queryByText('text')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});```


my error Error:
```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')```
````

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the actual [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#TestingForm) on how to test forms made by `react-hook-form`.  There is no need to invoke the `useForm` hook in the test.

Use the **ByRole** method when querying different elements because that's how users recognize your UI component.

1. Mock the Login function. Something like -

```
const mockLogin = jest.fn((email, password) => {
  return Promise.resolve({ email, password });
});
```

2. Tests for failures / incorrect submissions. Example -

```
it("should display matching error when email is invalid", async () => {
    fireEvent.input(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /email/i }), {
      target: {
        value: "test"
      }
    });

    fireEvent.input(screen.getByLabelText("password"), {
      target: {
        value: "password"
      }
    });

    fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole("button"));

    expect(await screen.findAllByRole("alert")).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(mockLogin).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /email/i }).value).toBe("test");
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("password").value).toBe("password");
  });
```

Comment: Yes, but in my case i have to provide control object:
```export function DimensionsInput({
  control,
  unit = 'cm',
  multiline = false,
  rows = 1,
  buttonAction,
  fieldId,
}: DimensionsInputProps): ReactElement {```

Comment: @adampicker Please create a working codesandbox so we can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a good alternative when you don't want to mock the `useForm` function https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668939/2774342